# MVC ActionMethod Controller events?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there an event that is fired prior to an action method being called in a controller? I have some common 'page control' specific variables that are passed from client to server in nearly all acton methods and would benefit from a hanlder that would allow me to retrieve these values and map them to my own data structures before the action method is executed. Kind of like a viewstate mechanism.

J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an event that is fired prior to an action method being called in a controller?

You could override the [`OnActionExecuting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) method. Another more reusable solution is to write a [custom action filter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs) and then decorate your controllers/actions with it or even declare it as a [global action filter](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/global-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3/) so that it applies to all the controllers and actions in the application.

Comment: Many thanks Darin. Does this event sound like the correct way to provide a solution to solve my problem? or is it acceptable to just keep passing the same vars round from client to server within a view/controller?

Comment: Mmm... ActionFilters is something I haven't explored yet so this method may be what I'm looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

based on the last part of your question

> allow me to retrieve these values and map them to my own data
>   structures before the action method is executed

i think you're probably going to be best served by looking into [custom model binding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx).  that way you can pull the data into a strongly typed parameter that looks how you want it to, but only so long as that parameter is present.

Comment: ok, I'll look into custom model binding, thanks for the pointer.